# How to dynamically control multiple Listboxes simultaneously in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have 5 listboxes in which I need to control at the same time, almost as if they were one listbox with columns.

I am trying to find a way in which when I select an item from any one of the listboxes and delete them, it will highlight and delete the other items in the corresponding index.

so far I am only able to delete the other indexed items only when I invoke curselection() on Listbox1, but if a user selects an item on listbox2 and calls the same, it'll throw an error because the variable is looking for listbox1.

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples of how to control multiple listboxes simultaneously anywhere.

Is it possible to have a `self.listbox[0, 1, 2, 3].curselection()` type of thing? or even an if statement that allows me to check `if self.listbox1.curselection() == True:` and then execute according.

This is the function anyway:

```
    def removeSeq(self, event=None):
        index = self.listbox1.curselection()[0]
        print(index)
##        self.listbox1.selection_set(1)

        
##        selectedItem = self.listbox2.curselection()

##        print(selectedItem)
##        self.listbox1.delete(selectedItem)
##        self.listbox2.delete(selectedItem)
##        self.listbox3.delete(selectedItem)
##        self.listbox4.delete(selectedItem)
##        self.listbox5.delete(selectedItem)
    pass
```

I've commented most of it out for test purposes, any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Connected list boxes sounds a lot like a `ttk.Treeview` to me. Have you look at it?

Comment: @TheLizzard I have, but it would require me to essentially re-write the functionality of my script, so I was wondering if there are any quick wins before I decide to rebuild around treeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your binding you can use `event.widget` to know which widget was clicked on. Then it's just a matter of getting the selection from that widget and applying it to the other listboxes.

Here's a simple example. To delete a row, double-click in any listbox:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MultiListbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for i in range(5):
            lb = tk.Listbox(self, height=10, exportselection=False)
            lb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
            for j in range(10):
                lb.insert("end", f"Listbox {i+1} value {j+1}")
            lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.removeSeq)

    def removeSeq(self, event):
        lb = event.widget
        curselection = lb.curselection()
        index = curselection[0] if curselection else None

        for listbox in self.winfo_children():
            listbox.delete(index)
  
root = tk.Tk()
mlb = MultiListbox(root)
mlb.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```